# Removing both single and double quotes from a string

Tags: php, str-replace, trim

I have being trying to remove both double and single quotes from a string,
it is not working. Here is what I mean

```
text = "Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language";
```

I would like to trim as this

```
new text = "Plagiarism is the wrongful appropriation and stealing and publication of another authors language";
```

I tried this - no way!

```
$newtext = trim(trim($text,"'"),'"');
```

I even tried this one too - still no way!

```
$newtext = str_replace( array( "'","'" ),'',$text);
```

I simply don't know what I am doing wrong here.
Please help. 
Thanks ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
$text = "Plagiarism is the \"wrongful appropriation\" and \"stealing and publication\" of another author's \"language";
echo str_replace( array( "'",'"' ),'',$text);
```

Comment: I tried adding the slashes, it didnt work   - str_replace( array( "'",'"' ),'',addslashes($text))